# How soon can I travel back to Ukraine after the refusal on the basis of insufficient cash on me?

Tags: visas, study, denial-of-entry, ukraine

I have a student visa for Ukraine but was refused entry on the basis of I don't have enough physical cash on me to take care of myself and that I panicked at the end of my interview.

The immigration officers brought me a document to sign which contains the reason why they refused my entry.

One immigration office I spoke with read it to me and said if I want to return I should come with enough money and come through a different airport preferably the one where my school is located and have them send an arrival letter to the airport.

My question is how soon can I travel back to Ukraine and my chances of me gaining entry this time round since I have enough money on me now (USD 2000)

Comment: Were you given any documentation when you were refused entry? What did Immigration say about returning?

Comment: I was asked to sign a paper

Comment: the immigration said I can decide to come back anytime ones they've returned me to my country

Comment: A paper saying what? Did they cancel your visa? Have you contacted the institution where you were planning to study for advice?

Comment: they paper had was basically the reason I was denied entry which was because I didn't have money on me to take care of myself and that I panicked at the end of the interview

Comment: I have contacted my agent and he called immigration to also ask why

Comment: they told him the same thing but the letter of arrival the school was supposed to send was in Kharkov airport because that's was my initial destination until my flight was cancelled

Comment: There is no reference to official subsistence requirements for Ukraine in https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/e-library/documents/policies/borders-and-visas/schengen/docs/handbook-annex_25.pdf however comonsense would indicate not travelling without evidence of funds. Just an opinion but I personally wouldn’t attempt reentry unless I had all of the relevant papers supporting the visa application with me, and could demonstrate the source of the $2000 in case you’re asked about it, since you couldn’t show any funds the first time around.

Comment: I did have money but you see this my first time and I thought keeping such a huge amount of money on my atm card would be safer

Comment: but from what you are saying it is possible ones I have all the relevant paper work and money on me this time round

Comment: I wouldn’t carry that much in cash either. The important point is to be able to show you have access to it eg the card itself plus a statement. Did the Border official tell you how much they’d expect you to have in cash? Please edit your original question to include all the extra information you’re giving in your various comments plus state exactly what the Border official told you about subsistence requirements. It’s hard for people to give you a helpful answer if we don’t have all the details.

Comment: yes they said for a visa such as mine at least 1000 dollars   okay I will do just that